# Hausdorff dimension of compact set

Tags: hausdorff-measure, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $S \subset X$. Let $\DeclareMathOperator{\diam}{diam}\diam(S)$ denote diameter
of $S$, that is $\diam(S) = \sup \{ d(x, y) \colon \: x, y \in S \}$. Let
$\delta > 0$, $s \ge 0$ and define
$$
H_{\delta}^s(S) = \inf \left\{  \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\diam \, U_i)^s \colon \enspace
S \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} U_i \: \land  \: \diam U_i < \delta  \right\}.
$$

Now, let $H^s(S) = \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} H^s_{\delta}(S) $. Then $H^s$ is a outer (Hausdorff) measure. (Hausdorff) dimension of set $S$ can be defined by 
$\dim_{\mathrm{Haus}}(S) = \inf \{ s \ge 0 \colon \: H^s(S) = 0  \} $.

My questions are:

1. If $S$ is a compact subset of $X$, is it possible that $\dim_{Haus}(S) = \infty$?
2. If in 1. it is possible, then, is there a way to define what would the (outer) measure of such set be? (Is there a way of generalizing outer Hausdorff measure to infinite-dimensional sets?)

Comment: The Hilbert cube has infinite Hausdorff dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to both questions. For 1., observe that $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ is compact by Tychonoff's theorem and is infinite dimensional. For 2., this can be achieved by using the generalization of Hausdorff measure described [at the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure#Generalizations), where instead of $(\textrm{diam} U_i)^s$ we use $\phi(\textrm{diam} U_i)$ for an appropriate gauge function $\phi$. When $\phi$ grows superpolynomially, you can get non-trivial Hausdorff measures defined for infinite dimensional metric spaces.